# Stack-Fields not displaying in create/edit page in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-nova

I have this `field function` inside my `Resource`:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
        Stack::make('Headings', [
            Text::make('Heading (en)'),
            Text::make('Heading (de)'),
            Text::make('Heading (ar)'),
        ]),
        Stack::make('Content', [
            Text::make('Content (en)'),
            Text::make('Content (de)'),
            Text::make('Content (ar)'),
        ]),
        Image::make('Image')->disk('public')->prunable(),
    ];
}
```

which produces this view:

[image]

but as soon as I want to `create/edit` an entry, it only shows the `image field` and not the `heading/content text fields`:

[image]

This problem occurs since I implemented the `Stack Fields`.

Comment: can explain more, we can't understand

Comment: _Stack fields are not shown on forms, and are only for stacking lines of text for display on the index and detail resource views_. [Stack Field](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#stack-field)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Stack field is not shown on forms and `showOnUpdating()` method doesn't work.

The only solution I found by now is to insert the field I need in the Stack one and then recall them later with a `hideFromIndex()` method.

Per your code:

```
        Stack::make('Titoli', [
            Text::make('Titolo', 'title'),

            Slug::make('Slug', 'slug')->from('title'),
        ])
        ->sortable(),

        Text::make('Titolo', 'title')
            ->rules('required', 'max:255')
            ->hideFromIndex(),

        Slug::make('Slug', 'slug')->from('title')
        ->hideFromIndex(),
```

Not much elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

reference @rx4storm solution, write a helper to keep thing easy :)

```php
<?php
trait HasStackFieldPatcher
{
    public function stackFieldPatch($fields): array
    {
        $patchFields = [];
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            if (get_class($field) == 'Laravel\Nova\Fields\Stack') {
                $patchFields[] = $field->hideFromDetail();
                foreach ($field->lines as $lineField) {
                    if ($lineField->showOnCreation !== false ||
                        $lineField->showOnUpdate !== false) {
                        
                        $cloneField = clone $lineField;
                        $cloneField
                            ->hideFromIndex()
                            ->hideFromDetail();
                        $patchFields[] = $cloneField;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $patchFields[] = $field;
            }
        }
        return $patchFields;
    }
}
```

and then use `HasStackFieldPatcher` via `stackFieldPatch()` to patch fields in your resource.

```php
use App\Nova\HasStackFieldPatcher;

/**
 * call `stackFieldPatch` to patch stack fields
 */
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return $this->stackFieldPatch([
        ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
        Stack::make('Headings', [
            Text::make('Heading (en)'),
            Text::make('Heading (de)'),
            Text::make('Heading (ar)'),
        ]),
        Stack::make('Content', [
            Text::make('Content (en)'),
            Text::make('Content (de)'),
            Text::make('Content (ar)'),
        ]),
        Image::make('Image')->disk('public')->prunable(),
    ]);
}
```

But it might be better to use the official solution: [Dynamic Field Methods](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#dynamic-field-methods)

```
fieldsForIndex
fieldsForDetail
fieldsForInlineCreate
fieldsForCreate
fieldsForUpdate
fieldsForPreview
```